# Pseudocode algorithm to check encoding of Turing machine

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines

My question goes like this:

> Write an algorithm (in pseudocode) that on input $w$, checks that $w$ encodes a valid Turing machine $\langle M\rangle$. e.g, you need to validate that the structure is correct, that $\delta(q_a,a)$ is undefined for every symbol $a$, etc.

Unfortunately, I got no idea how to tackle it. I have a clue that induction might be needed, but it didn't help me. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Whose question is that again? Hint: you are asked to check the *syntax*. Look at the formal definition of $\langle \_ \rangle$ and write an ad-hoc parser. Or, alternatively, model the syntax using a CFG and use a standard parsing algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding $\langle M \rangle$ of a TM, has a specific *structure*. All you need your algorithm to do, is to verify that the input string $w$ possesses the "correct" structure of a valid encoding.

Note, that there are many possible ways to define the encoding $\langle M \rangle$. For instance *one* possible such encoding, for $M=(Q,q_0,F,\Gamma,\Sigma, \sqcup, \delta)$ is 
$$ 1^{|Q|}01^{|\Gamma|}01^{|\Sigma|}0\delta_100\delta_200 \ldots \delta_{last}000$$
where each $\delta_i$ is one line of the transition function, such that if, for instance $\delta(q,a) = \{ p, b, d\}$ we encode it as $1^q01^a01^p01^b01^d$ with $d$ being the direction where the head moves, say Left=1, Right=2, Stay=3.

Remember that other encodings are possible, it depends on your definition!

However, assuming the above definition, I think you should be able to come up with an algorithm to verify if the encoding is valid or not.

For instance, is the input $w=0000000$ valid ?

> no, because it contains no states $Q$, etc.

What will you need to check for validity? Basically, only the following

> 0. that the formatting looks correct (no extra characters, ends with 000, etc,)
>  1. that all the sets exist (and behave correctly, e.g., $|\Gamma|>|\Sigma|$)
>  2. that $\delta$ is well defined (think, what does this mean)...